# Why can't I connect to an external database in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have the following settings in my Django application.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mydatabasename',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'davidfaux',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'mySecretPassword',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'sql.externalhost.com',        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

However, when I use `manage.py` to run my application, I get the following traceback.

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'davidfaux'@'75.156.124.202' (using password: YES)")
```

`75.156.124.202` is the IP address for the dedicated server hosting my Django application. However, my database lies on an external server as I specified in settings.py.

Why is Django seeking this database on the dedicated server rather than an external location as I had specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django isn't looking for the database on the dedicated server. The returned MySQL error messages means that you are connecting from `75.156.124.202` as you can only allow connections from specific hosts with MySQL.

This means there is probably some kind of authentication issue, try to connect from your server with a mysql client to `sql.externalhost.com` and ensure that you can connect to the database.

Comment: Specifically, you probably need to create a user `davidfaux@75.156.124.202` in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure of my user/password combo. However, I think you're right. I'm not connecting to the external database. I'm not sure how to allow external connections in mysql though. I tried to run `mysql` in terminal, but I got the error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'david'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

Comment: You'll have include the -p argument to make it ask for the password: `mysql -h 75.156.124.202 -u davidfaux -p`

Comment: Thank you! I decided to move the database to the same server as my application, but thanks for inspiring me to use `mysql -u david -p` commands. I had never tinkered with mysql in the terminal.